creating model class for my table class in laravel
I have created a table like:
public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('image_sliders', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id('image_sliders_id');            
            $table->text('body')->nullable();
            $table->string('image');
            $table->boolean('status')->default(1);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

Now I want to create respective Model class for my table.
I am confused that in some tutorial, it shows using protected $fillable...
class image_slider extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'body',
        'image'
  

];
}
And in some tutorial it shows using table name and primary key name.
class image_slider extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'image_sliders';
    protected $primarykey = 'image_sliders_id';
}

What is the difference between these two methods? Thank You!

$table specifying table property explicitly tells Laravel to use specified database table instead of default class name (plural) while $primarykey sets primary key to specified primary key instead of deault id key!! Kindly read the official doc rather than asking on SO at https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/eloquent#table-names and https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/eloquent#primary-keys

the tutorial you are following should not use image_slider as the model name to begin with

The $fillable attribute is used for the mass assignment protection in laravel
The table property is used when you not naming your model and table with the expected criteria for example if the table is called users, so the model should be User otherwise you will need to specify it manually
same also for primaryKey by default laravel will search for the id column
So in your case the table called image_sliders so your model should be ImageSlider

So in my case shall I have to use both
protected $table = 'image_sliders';     protected $primarykey = 'image_sliders_id';     protected $fillable = [         'body',         'image'     ];

yes, you could use all of them as you want

First, you need to learn Laravel's naming rules.
The best way is to create migrations at the same time as the model:
php artisan make:model ImageSlider -m

If you create the Eloquent model first, the table name will be determined automatically. Leave the ID as id. Laravel has general rules, so you should follow them without designing your own. If you use $table or $primarykey, you are breaking from Laravel's standard rules.
Convention over configuration also applies to Laravel.
It's all written in the official docs. Don't believe unofficial tutorial articles, as they are all written by beginners who don't understand Laravel.
